# .htaccess - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I migrated my site to other domain, but I have a trouble with Access-Control-Allow-Origin - fonts not show in new site, I was changed already .htacces but
the new site is still read all `.css` from my old site. Please advise, what is the problem.

old site .htaccess

hlidanimazlicka.cz/test

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

new site .htaccess

studio120.eu

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

# nginx config
#if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
# add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
#}
```

Comment: thank you hjpotter92 for edit

Comment: Have you confirmed with a client that the header is not emitted? Have you confirmed the .htaccess file is being read by typing gibberish into it and checking for an error?

Comment: Hi,thank you for reply. What do you mean "emitted" I was the owner to this two domains. I´m a beginner ,i don´t know what is "typing gibberish"
i need to delete content/files on the old site. I need totally migrate not redirect.

Comment: I only mean "is the header you expect sent". it's important to check one piece at a time.

Comment: Hmm Its strange. Check source now, link to all .css is OK. I deleted the .access file from old site....and works

Comment: i dont know, what happened?

Comment: maybe browser cache?  Always a good idea to test incognito or w/ a command line client.